# AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'MultiPolygonField'

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, postgis

I face the problem:

```
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'MultiPolygonField'.
```

It was thrown by django when I trying to `makemigrations`. Old file of migrations (only 1 makemigrations file was done) was deleted. So Django, thinks for some reason that I import `django.db.models` instead of `django.contrib.gis.db`.

There is problem part my models.py code (off cause code break on 'geom' field line)

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from renter.models import *
from classification_list.models import*

class ForestryKeys(models.Model):

    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    df_forestry = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True),
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(geography=True, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='gmtry')

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        verbose_name = 'frst'
        verbose_name_plural =  'frtses'
```

Comment: Do you encounter this error in this `models.py` file or somewhere else?

Comment: No, I didn't. There is  answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the 'star imports'. You did import `django.contrib.gis.db.models`, but then it was replaced on the following lines.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from renter.models import *  # this could replace models with django.db.models
from classification_list.models import *  # and so could this
```

The best fixes are to explicitly import the models you need,

```
from renter.models import MyModel1
from classification_list.models import MyModel2
```

or to import the `renter.models` module

```
import renter.models as renter_models
import from classification_list.models as classification_models *  
# now use renter_models.MyModel1, classification_models.MyModel2
```

As a hack, you could swap the order of the models, but it's much better to use one of the approaches above.

```
from renter.models import *
from classification_list.models import *  
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
```